# Filter DF using the column of another DF (same col in both DF) Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

**I am trying to filter a DataFrame DF1 using the column of another DataFrame DF2**, the col is country_id. I Want to reduce all the rows of the first DataFrame to only the countries that there are on the second DF. An example:

```
+--------------+------------+-------+
|Date          | country_id | value |
+--------------+------------+-------+
|2015-12-14    |ARG         |5      |
|2015-12-14    |GER         |1      |
|2015-12-14    |RUS         |1      |
|2015-12-14    |CHN         |3      |
|2015-12-14    |USA         |1      |


+--------------+------------+
|USE           | country_id |
+--------------+------------+
|  F           |RUS         |
|  F           |CHN         |

Expected:

+--------------+------------+-------+
|Date          | country_id | value |
+--------------+------------+-------+
|2015-12-14    |RUS         |1      |
|2015-12-14    |CHN         |3      |
```

How could I do this? I am new with Spark so I have thought on use maybe intersect? or would be more efficient other method?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use left semi join:

```
val DF3 = DF1.join(DF2, Seq("country_id"), "left_semi")

DF3.show

//+----------+----------+-----+
//|country_id|      Date|value|
//+----------+----------+-----+
//|       RUS|2015-12-14|    1|
//|       CHN|2015-12-14|    3|
//+----------+----------+-----+
```

You can also use inner join :

```
val DF3 = DF1.alias("a").join(DF2.alias("b"), Seq("country_id")).select("a.*")
```

Comment: That is! left_semi is what I was looking for! Is my first time reading about left_semi and left_anti, thanks for your time and for open my eyes a little bit more in this world!!

Comment: Blackbishop, it is posible to do this and mantein just one column of the second DF? (for example select the column USE) asking you to not open another thread. Thanks in advance!